# Need help querying azure mobile service database

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services, querying

I am trying to query an azure mobile service database for a specific record. I need the query to find the record whose `NotifyDate` column equals the current date. Then from the record that is found, I want to take the string value that is in the record's `Name` column and store it in a string that I can use outside of the database.

This is what I've come up with, but it is giving me an error:

> Cannot convert method group 'ToString' to non delegate type 'string'. 
>   Did you intend to invoke the method?

At the following line:

```
string NotifyDate = FindNotifyDate().ToString;
```

Is there a better way that you can think of to do this?

Current Code:

```
private IMobileServiceTable<TodoItem> todoTable =
 MobileService.GetTable<TodoItem>();

private MobileServiceCollection<TodoItem, TodoItem> items;
private List<TodoItem> notifyItems;

protected void Application_Start()
{
    WebApiConfig.Register();
    string NotifyDate = FindNotifyDate().ToString;
}

public async Task<TodoItem> FindNotifyDate()
{
    DateTime test = DateTime.Now;
    test = test.AddMilliseconds(-test.Millisecond);
    notifyItems = await todoTable.Where(todoItem => todoItem.NotifyDate == test)
                                 .ToListAsync();
    return notifyItems[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following code

```
    protected void async Application_Start()
    {
        WebApiConfig.Register();
        var todoItem = await FindNotifyDate();
        string NotifyDate = todoItem.ToString();
    }
```

`FindNotifyDate` is async operation. You have to wait for it's completion in order to call `ToString()` of `TodoItem`. Otherwise in your example you get [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) as result type and it's not what you were expecting. Make it sync operation to call `ToString()` immediately after call or wait for completion as in above sample.

Comment: Also, you should rename FindNotifyDate() to FindNotifyDateAsync() to follow C# async conventions.

Comment: I think you're missing the parenthesis after ToString. The line should read: string NotifyDate = todoItem.ToString(); Without the parenthesis you'll get the same error as in the original question.